# SpecFlow Example with azure-pipelines.yml for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, specflow

I am trying to get a simple SpecFlow+ example up and running on Azure DevOps.

Currently I get the following Error Message:

> SpecFlow+LivingDoc: An error happened during the execution: The SDK
>   'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

1. How do I install the required "Microsoft .NET Test SDK 15"?
2. Can somebody point me to a simple example SpecFlow setup for Azure DevOps?

All details can be found on this public Azure DevOps project:
https://dev.azure.com/FlorianBoehmak/_git/SpecFlowCalculator

---

EDIT

Thanks @Levi Lu-MSFT for pointing me into the right direction. I put everything together into a github repository (including a devops generator). Enjoy :-)

https://github.com/fnbk/SpecFlowCalculator

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the yaml pipeline definition, it seems that the `vstest task` didnot specify the test .dll file. You can try specifying the test dlls like below.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\Calculator.Spec.dll
      !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

And if your project is a .net core project, the Project file path field in the SpecFlow+
is the path containing your project, not the project itself. You can try setting the projectfilepath to you root directory of your source repo like below.[check here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlowPlus-Resources/wiki/Configuring-the-Build-Step-in-DevOps)

```
- task: SpecFlowPlus@0
  inputs:
    projectFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    projectLanguage: 'en'
```

Hope above can be of some help!